# Circuit Simulation For Mac

Tags: simulation, software

I was wondering if anybody is aware of any up and coming circuit simulators for mac? I have a little bit of experience with National Instruments Multisim and I quite like its layout and functionality.

I know that I could purchase a virtual machine environment (Parallels) with the Windows OS and run Multisim, but I was curious whether or not a fully featured software would be arriving for Mac. I've used iCircuit a bit and it is fun to play around with, it lacks the robust circuit library of a  Multisim.

I'm amazed by the lack of EE software available for the Mac in 2015.

Comment: Purchase VM? Isn't there free VirtualBox? You don't have to buy everything, even if you are Mac..

Comment: You really shouldn't be amazed. The Mac ecosystem is designed for people that don't want to worry about technical details, aka. artists, people browsing and checking email, etc. Engineers and scientists have been using Windows and Linux for decades. Why would EDA tool makers concentrate on developing something for a market that has no use for their products?

Comment: @MattYoung While that was true until like 5 years ago, today the picture is different. I have a good friend, an engineer, totally linux-head for decades. Recently have got a macbook. Guess what? He have switched the religion. He says "It's like Linux, but it works".

Comment: lol. Easy on the Mac hate. I've had this for 2 years now and it still running solid -- unlike my PC laptops that end up getting bogged down before the end of its first year.   I didn't think VB performed as well with something designed specifically for Mac...?

Comment: I think that may have been true several years ago @Matt, but I believe that is changing and would change more quickly if the software was readily available.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That may be the case, but it's going to take a lot more than a couple guys getting Macbooks to uproot the market. Take Altium for example. Its origins trace back to the mid 80's. There is a lot of history there, and porting it over to Mac without a user base just isn't good business.

Comment: @wellington Use me as an example, been using Windows since Windows 95. Why should I switch to Mac when all my software works and is stable on Windows? This is the vicious cycle.

Comment: @MattYoung If you see a clear evidence that it is better (hypothetically), wouldn't you switch?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Define better. It would take something pretty damn miraculous for me to buy an overpriced computer and get everything working as well as it is now.

Comment: Runs faster, smoother, more stable and looks nicer :) You name it. Anyway, it's like a religion if you don't look at it critically. But if a tool is better, and the advantage is justifying the price - I would switch the tool.

Comment: I'm not saying that you should switch. I wanted to try it after reading many positive reviews -- overall lifetime, performance, integrated software..etc. But there is a younger generation that is growing up using iPhones and Mac's...the software will come. I'm just not sure when.

Comment: I think Apple has definitely put too much of its focus on, as you said, "artists" and the nontechnical, that its created a negative image for those that are technical. I'm just hoping they eventually shift their focus a bit and put more effort into STEM software.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You can argue that point all you want, what I'm getting at is an entire profession of people isn't going to uproot their tools because something is "smoother" or "looks nicer." Maybe that will change in a decade, but I really doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered that LTSpice is now available as a native Mac implementation.  Download it from Linear Technology for free.

It seems to work like the windows implementation although the menus are done differently.  It can use the same netlist files.

I have also used LTSpice under VirtualBox (free from Oracle) with no problems. You have to install windows in the VM with this approach.

LTSpice will run under Crossover on a Mac.  This does not require that you install Windows.  There were a few quirks with some of the dialog boxes but it was very usable.

Comment: I have actually used it a time or two, but ended up using Multisim (EE course required software) and by default became very familiar with it. I will have another go with LTSpice. Hopefully I won't start reminiscing about the good ol days with Multisim. haha. Thanks for recommendation!